# Module imports within a package, python - setuptools

Tags: python

So my file system looks something like this

```
/projects
--setup.py
--setup.cfg
--/app
--/--__init__.py
--/--app.py
--/--file_with_class.py
```

In my app.py I import file_with_class.py, but when I use setup to install my module with pip install . and try running it, I get this error:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'className'
```

supose file_with_class.py contains a class named className like so:

```py
class className():
  def __init__():
    pass
```

I'm importing this class in app.py like this:

```py
from file_with_class import className
```

Also, when executing app.py on its own it works perfectly, the problem comes when creating the package with setuptools and after installing my own package, trying to run it.

Comment: Are you importing anything from `app` package in the `setup.py` script?

Comment: I'm using packages = find in my setup.cfg, was that your question??

Comment: I mean, is there any statement like `from app import` or `from .app` in your file?

Comment: Not in setup.py, but it isnt required, or at least I haven't seen it anywhere

Comment: Since the situation is quite ambiguous, can you use `packages=find_packages()` in your `setup.py` script? See if that resolves that problem.

Comment: I've already set it up like and still no ressults

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and it had to do with relative paths.

```py
from file_with_class import className`
```

This will look for a installed package called `file_with_class`, not the file `file_with_class.py`.

To use relative paths, add a `.` before the file name as such:

```py
from .file_with_class import className
```

This should point to your file, rather than a installed package.